Issues with extracting images using bounding polygons from PDF with PyMuPDF
I'm working on a project where I need to extract specific images from a PDF using bounding polygons provided by Azure's Form Recognizer as JSON format. I'm using PyMuPDF (Fitz) to handle the PDF processing.
The problem
I'm attempting to extract images from the PDF based on the polygon coordinates. The polygons are provided in the JSON output from the Form Recognizer, and they are specified in inches relative to the top-left corner of the page. However, I'm encountering some issues where the extracted images do not match the expected regions or fail to extract correctly.
import fitz  # PyMuPDF
import os
from typing import List, Dict

class PDFImageExtractor:
    def __init__(self, pdf_path: str, output_folder: str, json_data: Dict):
        self.pdf_path = pdf_path
        self.output_folder = output_folder
        self.json_data = json_data.get('analyzeResult', {}).get('figures', [])
        self.ensure_directory()

    def ensure_directory(self):
        if not os.path.exists(self.output_folder):
            os.makedirs(self.output_folder) 

    def extract_images(self) -> Dict[str, str]:
        pdf_document = fitz.open(self.pdf_path)
        image_filenames = {}

        for figure in self.json_data:
            polygon = figure["boundingRegions"][0]["polygon"]
            page_number = figure["boundingRegions"][0]["pageNumber"] - 1

            # Debug: Print polygon data before processing
            print(f"Processing figure {figure['id']} on page {page_number + 1} with polygon: {polygon}")

            # Ensure polygon has exactly 4 points (8 coordinates)
            if len(polygon) >= 8:
                quad_polygon = polygon[:8]  # Take the first 4 points (8 coordinates)
                image_filename = self.extract_image_from_polygon(quad_polygon, page_number, figure["id"])
                if image_filename:
                    image_filenames[figure["id"]] = image_filename
            else:
                print(f"Polygon for figure {figure['id']} does not have enough points: {polygon}")
        
        pdf_document.close()
        return image_filenames

    def extract_image_from_polygon(self, polygon: List[float], page_number: int, image_id: str) -> str:
        pdf_document = fitz.open(self.pdf_path)
        page = pdf_document.load_page(page_number)
        mat = fitz.Matrix(2, 2)  # Scaling the matrix for better resolution

        # Get the actual dimensions of the page
        page_width = page.rect.width
        page_height = page.rect.height
        print(f"Page dimensions (width x height): {page_width} x {page_height}")

        if len(polygon) == 8:
            # Convert normalized coordinates to actual page coordinates
            actual_polygon = [
                polygon[0] * page_width, polygon[1] * page_height,
                polygon[2] * page_width, polygon[3] * page_height,
                polygon[4] * page_width, polygon[5] * page_height,
                polygon[6] * page_width, polygon[7] * page_height
            ]

            # Print actual polygon coordinates for debugging
            print(f"Actual polygon coordinates: {actual_polygon}")

            # Create a fitz.Rect object from the polygon coordinates
            try:
                # Convert to fitz.Point
                points = [fitz.Point(actual_polygon[i], actual_polygon[i + 1]) for i in range(0, len(actual_polygon), 2)]
                rect = fitz.Rect(points[0], points[2])
                print(f"Rect for clipping: {rect}")

                # Define the clipping rectangle based on the quad
                clip_rect = rect.intersect(page.rect)
                print(f"Clip rectangle: {clip_rect}")

                if clip_rect.is_empty:
                    raise ValueError("Clipping rectangle is outside the page boundaries")

                # Extract image based on the quad
                pix = page.get_pixmap(matrix=mat, clip=clip_rect)
                image_filename = os.path.join(self.output_folder, f"image_{image_id}.png")
                pix.save(image_filename)
                print(f"Image saved as {image_filename}")
                return image_filename
            except ValueError as e:
                print(f"Error processing image {image_id} with polygon {actual_polygon}: {e}")
                return None
            except fitz.FitzError as e:
                print(f"MuPDF Error: {e}")
                return None
        else:
            print(f"Invalid polygon for image {image_id}: {polygon}")
            return None

# Example usage
extractor = PDFImageExtractor("path/to/pdf.pdf", "output_images", json_data)
image_filenames = extractor.extract_images()
print(image_filenames)

Issue details

Polygon coordinates: The polygons sometimes seem to have coordinates outside the expected range (greater than the page dimensions). I'm unsure if I’m correctly converting the coordinates from the JSON data to the actual page dimensions.

Image extraction: Some images aren't being extracted correctly, or the clipped regions don't match the expected areas on the page.


Example data
Here is a sample of the JSON data I'm working with:
{
    "analyzeResult": {
        "figures": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "boundingRegions": [
                    {
                        "polygon": [1.6787, 2.1239, 3.3841, 2.124, 3.3838, 2.87, 1.6784, 2.87],
                        "pageNumber": 1
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}

Output result
Processing figure 1.1 on page 1 with polygon: [1.6787, 2.1239, 3.3841, 2.124, 3.3838, 2.87, 1.6784, 2.87]
Actual polygon coordinates: [998.7592864257813, 1788.1538517028807, 2013.4040038085939, 1788.238043701172, 2013.2255158203125, 2416.3103509521484, 998.5807984374999, 2416.3103509521484]
Formed Quad: Quad(Point(998.7592864257813, 1788.1538517028807), Point(2013.4040038085939, 1788.238043701172), Point(2013.2255158203125, 2416.3103509521484), Point(998.5807984374999, 2416.3103509521484))
Error processing image 1.1 with polygon [998.7592864257813, 1788.1538517028807, 2013.4040038085939, 1788.238043701172, 2013.2255158203125, 2416.3103509521484, 998.5807984374999, 2416.3103509521484]: Clipping rectangle is outside the page boundaries
Processing figure 1.2 on page 1 with polygon: [0.5343, 5.3751, 7.7137, 5.3724, 7.7131, 9.4054, 0.5341, 9.4088]
Actual polygon coordinates: [317.8871071289062, 4525.40410014038, 4589.342650683594, 4523.130916186523, 4588.985674707031, 7918.594207263184, 317.76811513671873, 7921.456735205077]
Formed Quad: Quad(Point(317.8871071289062, 4525.40410014038), Point(4589.342650683594, 4523.130916186523), Point(4588.985674707031, 7918.594207263184), Point(317.76811513671873, 7921.456735205077))
Error processing image 1.2 with polygon [317.8871071289062, 4525.40410014038, 4589.342650683594, 4523.130916186523, 4588.985674707031, 7918.594207263184, 317.76811513671873, 7921.456735205077]: Clipping rectangle is outside the page boundaries
Processing figure 2.1 on page 2 with polygon: [0.5332, 2.6063, 7.7237, 2.6062, 7.7226, 6.6617, 0.5325, 6.6627]
Actual polygon coordinates: [317.232651171875, 2194.2960514587403, 4595.292250292969, 2194.211859460449, 4594.6377943359375, 5608.6183501525875, 316.8161791992187, 5609.460270135498]
Formed Quad: Quad(Point(317.232651171875, 2194.2960514587403), Point(4595.292250292969, 2194.211859460449), Point(4594.6377943359375, 5608.6183501525875), Point(316.8161791992187, 5609.460270135498))
Error processing image 2.1 with polygon [317.232651171875, 2194.2960514587403, 4595.292250292969, 2194.211859460449, 4594.6377943359375, 5608.6183501525875, 316.8161791992187, 5609.460270135498]: Clipping rectangle is outside the page boundaries
Processing figure 5.1 on page 5 with polygon: [0.6089, 4.7202, 1.1627, 4.7203, 1.1625, 5.3616, 0.6088, 5.3616]
Actual polygon coordinates: [362.27112021484373, 3974.03070333252, 691.7599465820313, 3974.1148953308107, 691.6409545898438, 4514.038180371094, 362.21162421875, 4514.038180371094]
Formed Quad: Quad(Point(362.27112021484373, 3974.03070333252), Point(691.7599465820313, 3974.1148953308107), Point(691.6409545898438, 4514.038180371094), Point(362.21162421875, 4514.038180371094))
Error processing image 5.1 with polygon [362.27112021484373, 3974.03070333252, 691.7599465820313, 3974.1148953308107, 691.6409545898438, 4514.038180371094, 362.21162421875, 4514.038180371094]: Clipping rectangle is outside the page boundaries
Processing figure 5.2 on page 5 with polygon: [0.6191, 5.7144, 1.0935, 5.7144, 1.0933, 6.2406, 0.619, 6.2406]
Actual polygon coordinates: [368.33971181640624, 4811.067550341797, 650.5887172851562, 4811.067550341797, 650.4697252929687, 5254.085845349121, 368.2802158203125, 5254.085845349121]
Formed Quad: Quad(Point(368.33971181640624, 4811.067550341797), Point(650.5887172851562, 4811.067550341797), Point(650.4697252929687, 5254.085845349121), Point(368.2802158203125, 5254.085845349121))
Error processing image 5.2 with polygon [368.33971181640624, 4811.067550341797, 650.5887172851562, 4811.067550341797, 650.4697252929687, 5254.085845349121, 368.2802158203125, 5254.085845349121]: Clipping rectangle is outside the page boundaries
Processing figure 5.3 on page 5 with polygon: [0.5977, 7.8534, 1.0848, 7.8535, 1.0845, 8.3809, 0.5975, 8.3809]
Actual polygon coordinates: [355.60756865234373, 6611.934393786621, 645.412565625, 6612.018585784913, 645.2340776367188, 7056.047184771729, 355.48857666015624, 7056.047184771729]
Formed Quad: Quad(Point(355.60756865234373, 6611.934393786621), Point(645.412565625, 6612.018585784913), Point(645.2340776367188, 7056.047184771729), Point(355.48857666015624, 7056.047184771729))
Error processing image 5.3 with polygon [355.60756865234373, 6611.934393786621, 645.412565625, 6612.018585784913, 645.2340776367188, 7056.047184771729, 355.48857666015624, 7056.047184771729]: Clipping rectangle is outside the page boundaries
Processing figure 5.4 on page 5 with polygon: [0.5807, 10.7543, 1.0882, 10.7543, 1.0882, 11.2812, 0.5807, 11.2812]
Actual polygon coordinates: [345.49324931640626, 9054.260072210694, 647.4354294921875, 9054.260072210694, 647.4354294921875, 9497.867711206054, 345.49324931640626, 9497.867711206054]
Formed Quad: Quad(Point(345.49324931640626, 9054.260072210694), Point(647.4354294921875, 9054.260072210694), Point(647.4354294921875, 9497.867711206054), Point(345.49324931640626, 9497.867711206054))
Error processing image 5.4 with polygon [345.49324931640626, 9054.260072210694, 647.4354294921875, 9054.260072210694, 647.4354294921875, 9497.867711206054, 345.49324931640626, 9497.867711206054]: Clipping rectangle is outside the page boundaries
Processing figure 6.1 on page 6 with polygon: [0.5858, 1.9932, 1.0643, 1.9932, 1.0643, 2.4856, 0.5859, 2.4857]
Actual polygon coordinates: [348.5275451171875, 1678.1149099365234, 633.2158864257813, 1678.1149099365234, 633.2158864257813, 2092.676309521484, 348.58704111328126, 2092.7605015197755]
Formed Quad: Quad(Point(348.5275451171875, 1678.1149099365234), Point(633.2158864257813, 1678.1149099365234), Point(633.2158864257813, 2092.676309521484), Point(348.58704111328126, 2092.7605015197755))
Error processing image 6.1 with polygon [348.5275451171875, 1678.1149099365234, 633.2158864257813, 1678.1149099365234, 633.2158864257813, 2092.676309521484, 348.58704111328126, 2092.7605015197755]: Clipping rectangle is outside the page boundaries
Processing figure 6.2 on page 6 with polygon: [0.5967, 2.6856, 1.069, 2.6856, 1.0689, 3.2238, 0.5966, 3.2238]
Actual polygon coordinates: [355.01260869140623, 2261.060306103516, 636.0121982421874, 2261.060306103516, 635.9527022460937, 2714.181640905762, 354.9531126953125, 2714.181640905762]
Formed Quad: Quad(Point(355.01260869140623, 2261.060306103516), Point(636.0121982421874, 2261.060306103516), Point(635.9527022460937, 2714.181640905762), Point(354.9531126953125, 2714.181640905762))
Error processing image 6.2 with polygon [355.01260869140623, 2261.060306103516, 636.0121982421874, 2261.060306103516, 635.9527022460937, 2714.181640905762, 354.9531126953125, 2714.181640905762]: Clipping rectangle is outside the page boundaries
Processing figure 6.3 on page 6 with polygon: [0.5879, 4.8296, 1.0677, 4.8296, 1.0676, 5.358, 0.5878, 5.3581]
Actual polygon coordinates: [349.77696103515626, 4066.1367494628907, 635.2387502929688, 4066.1367494628907, 635.1792542968751, 4511.007268432617, 349.7174650390625, 4511.091460430908]
Formed Quad: Quad(Point(349.77696103515626, 4066.1367494628907), Point(635.2387502929688, 4066.1367494628907), Point(635.1792542968751, 4511.007268432617), Point(349.7174650390625, 4511.091460430908))
Error processing image 6.3 with polygon [349.77696103515626, 4066.1367494628907, 635.2387502929688, 4066.1367494628907, 635.1792542968751, 4511.007268432617, 349.7174650390625, 4511.091460430908]: Clipping rectangle is outside the page boundaries
Processing figure 6.4 on page 6 with polygon: [0.5739, 7.3517, 1.0721, 7.3516, 1.0719, 7.8893, 0.5738, 7.8894]
Actual polygon coordinates: [341.44752158203124, 6189.543138360596, 637.8565741210938, 6189.458946362305, 637.7375821289063, 6642.159321173096, 341.3880255859375, 6642.243513171386]
Formed Quad: Quad(Point(341.44752158203124, 6189.543138360596), Point(637.8565741210938, 6189.458946362305), Point(637.7375821289063, 6642.159321173096), Point(341.3880255859375, 6642.243513171386))
Error processing image 6.4 with polygon [341.44752158203124, 6189.543138360596, 637.8565741210938, 6189.458946362305, 637.7375821289063, 6642.159321173096, 341.3880255859375, 6642.243513171386]: Clipping rectangle is outside the page boundaries
Processing figure 6.5 on page 6 with polygon: [0.5997, 9.1592, 1.059, 9.1592, 1.059, 9.6817, 0.5997, 9.6818]
Actual polygon coordinates: [356.79748857421873, 7711.313507470703, 630.0625986328124, 7711.313507470703, 630.0625986328124, 8151.21669854126, 356.79748857421873, 8151.300890539552]
Formed Quad: Quad(Point(356.79748857421873, 7711.313507470703), Point(630.0625986328124, 7711.313507470703), Point(630.0625986328124, 8151.21669854126), Point(356.79748857421873, 8151.300890539552))
Error processing image 6.5 with polygon [356.79748857421873, 7711.313507470703, 630.0625986328124, 7711.313507470703, 630.0625986328124, 8151.21669854126, 356.79748857421873, 8151.300890539552]: Clipping rectangle is outside the page boundaries
Processing figure 6.6 on page 6 with polygon: [0.5741, 10.2071, 1.0748, 10.2071, 1.0747, 10.7515, 0.5741, 10.7516]
Actual polygon coordinates: [341.5665135742188, 8593.561457562257, 639.4629660156249, 8593.561457562257, 639.4034700195313, 9051.902696258545, 341.5665135742188, 9051.986888256835]
Formed Quad: Quad(Point(341.5665135742188, 8593.561457562257), Point(639.4629660156249, 8593.561457562257), Point(639.4034700195313, 9051.902696258545), Point(341.5665135742188, 9051.986888256835))
Error processing image 6.6 with polygon [341.5665135742188, 8593.561457562257, 639.4629660156249, 8593.561457562257, 639.4034700195313, 9051.902696258545, 341.5665135742188, 9051.986888256835]: Clipping rectangle is outside the page boundaries
{}

Am I correctly interpreting the polygon coordinates, considering that they are in inches? How can I ensure that they correctly map to the page dimensions? Could the scaling factor be affecting the accuracy of the clipping? Should I consider a different approach?
Here is an image of how Document Intelligence maps the polygons:
Document Intelligence Image
These polygon coordinates give me an image of the whole page:
"polygon": [0, 0, 612, 0, 612, 792, 0, 792],


What I ahve found out so far is that the polygon coords go clockwise from top left corner all the way to the bottom left corner. the issue is now the normalization.

You need to use dpi or the resolution of the image in pdf and not the width and height.
So, you replace width and height with below code in your function extract_image_from_polygon
page_xres = page.get_pixmap().xres
page_yres = page.get_pixmap().yres

And for my below page 1 in pdf.

Output:


when replacing ´page_width = page.rect.width page_height = page.rect.height´ with page_xres = page.get_pixmap().xres
page_yres = page.get_pixmap().yres I dont get the right frame of the images yet, but i still do get images generated for me.

I set the height and width to 72 and now the frames are okay, I get the images generated and they are fine, the images were not very wellp clipped but they are fine.

Your co-ordinates are in effect unitless digital values for polygons legs (nothing whatsoever to do with dpi or other unit ratios).
Since you say they nominally represent in this case "inches". Then they simply need to be multiplied by 72 and will then show their position on any /UserUnits 1  page.
Here they are placed on any nominal page irrespective of the contents.

Here is that PDF as text, so you can check my rounding off to nearest 0.1
7 0 obj
<</Length 363>>
stream
q 612 0 0 792 0 0 cm /FXE1 gs /FXX1 Do Q q 1 0 0 -1 0 792 cm   /FXE1 gs
38.5 387.0 m
555.4 387.0 l
555.4 677.3 l
38.5 677.3 l
38.5 387.0 l

h 1 0 0 RG  S 

120.9 152.9 m
243.6 152.9 l
243.6 206.6 l
120.9 206.6 l
120.9 152.9 l 

h 1 0 0 RG S Q Q

endstream
endobj

If the images are discrete JPEG (as they appear they should be). Then there is no need for clipping, as they would be exportable as JPEG in their native state at their own 1:1 scale. With any internal Metadata self adjusting their size and density on extraction.
If that is the case then Mutool rather than PyMupdf can do that as a OS shell single line command.

I understand, thank you!
